# How to disable appearing of ToolTip text over ToolStripButton?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip, toolstripbutton

I trying to display own custom ToolTip with image, but the native ToolTip makes all bad.
It still appears where it no needed.

I creating ToolStripButton in that way:

```
ToolStripButton btn = new ToolStripButton();
btn.Text = name;
btn.ToolTipText = null; //I also tried string.Empty, but no luck
```

What else I can do to disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following setting:

```
btn.AutoToolTip = false;
btn.ToolTipText = string.empty;
```

The note on the [AutoToolTip property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripbutton.autotooltip(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Set the AutoToolTip property to false to display custom ToolTipText on a ToolStripItem.

Comment: Even that doesn't work for me, it still shows a tooltip with the same text as the button text

Comment: @PandaWood You would have to document that in a question with repeatable code.

Answer (score 3):

You can also disable all tooltips just go to toolstrip properties and then select **False**

[image]